# Quarkus failed to start when database generation set to update in quarkus-hibernate-reactive

Tags: quarkus, hibernate-reactive

Working with quarkus-hibernate-reactive i caught an error(Stacktrace shown below). The error occured when i set the property `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update` to update. `drop-and-create` working fine.

application.properties

```
quarkus.http.port=8085
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=admin
quarkus.datasource.password=admin
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5000/keycloak_sample
myapp.schema.create=true

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStateNotification.waitForApplicationStart(ApplicationStateNotification.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartApp(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:191)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartCallback(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:175)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:254)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:64)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:54)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:918)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:100)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$3.run(StartupActionImpl.java:134)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ReactiveSessionFactoryImpl.java:33)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.boot.FastBootReactiveEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootReactiveEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:118)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:42)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll$$superaccessor5(JPAConfig_Subclass.zig:763)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass$$function$$5.apply(JPAConfig_Subclass$$function$$5.zig:29)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:63)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll(JPAConfig_Subclass.zig:721)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:88)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.deploy_0(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.zig:74)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.deploy(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.zig:40)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:764)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Not using JDBC
    at org.hibernate.reactive.provider.service.NoJdbcConnectionProvider.getConnection(NoJdbcConnectionProvider.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Hibernate Reactive only works with the options for the creating and dropping tables on the database. Update and validation hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: supported now. tested with version 2.13.2.Final